# GWT how to setup Pager in DataGrid when using Objectify Cursors

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, objectify

I recently got it to the point where I can retrieve data with a Cursor (see this link: [GWT pass Objectify Cursor from Server to Client with RequestFactory and show more pages in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058737/gwt-pass-objectify-cursor-from-server-to-client-with-requestfactory-and-show-mor))

what I am running into - when I get the data pack on the client side its only a List of 25 - when I go to set the data in the DataGrid the pager on the bottom says showing 1-25 of 25, there are obviously more records in the database I'm just retrieving 25 of them at a time with the cursor

What I tried doing is setting the following:

```
pager.setRangeLimited(false);
```

Unfortunately - while this allows me to page and select more from the database - it never actually gives me the amount in the database.  What I am wondering is, if I'm using a Cursor on the server side - how do I set the total count in the Pager??

One thing i thought about doing is simply adding a total count variable to the ListCursor wrapper object i'm returning - unfortunately this would require that if i request it with a null initial query i go through and get the total count every time - this seems horribly inefficient - and then once i get this back I still have no idea how to actually tell the pager that more data is available than i actually gave it.

Any help on this would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You set the total count in the pager by telling the pager that the row count is exact :

```
asyncDataProvider.updateRowCount(int size, boolean exact);
```

If you don't tell the pager that the row count is exact, then you can obviously not navigate to the last page.

The core issue is how to get hold of the total row count. Querying the row count is indeed highly inefficient. A better bet would be to keep a counter in the data store that tracks the number of records. This can be quite inefficient too, because you have the increment this counter synchronized/transactional.

In my project, I dont keep track of the exact row count but I provide flexible search options.